Всех приветствую! Подскажите, как с помощью регулярного выражения вытащить значения только по name='assigned_to'?
<select id='id_owners' name='assigned_to' multiple='selected' size='5'>
  <option value='-1'>Unassigned</option>
  <option value='173'>oztdellil</option>
  <option value='28'>eleizzcfb</option>
</select>

<select name='saved_query' id='id_query_selector'>
  <option value='-1'>Unassigned</option>
  <option value='3'>hello</option>
  <option value='5'>kakoe-to message</option>
  <option value='8'>hello lanit</option>
</select>


Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос. 1. Что именно вы хотите вытащить — текстовое содержимое всего блока, названия полей, value? 2. Зачем вам регулярка и в каком контексте? Как задать хороший вопрос?

Нужно вытащить содержимое value (-1, 173, 28) из 'assigned_to', для того чтобы потом рандомно передать эти значения в следующем запросе

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11610501 объясняется, почему ни в коем случае нельзя парсить HTML с помощью регулярных выражений.

@AS-v ещё раз перечитайте Как задать хороший вопрос? и исправьте и дополните сам вопрос. К тому же я спрашивал про контекст происходящего, т.е. о программной среде того, где вам это нужно сделать, поскольку, раз уж вы собираетесь куда-то передавать эти значения, то вероятнее всего можно обойтись языком, а не голой регуляркой.
